# Dynamically Select Element from Dynamically Generated List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to  select an element from a dynamically generated list of elements at the event of a touch. I am generating the list with a for loop. In each element I add an event listener and push the navigation stack to another screen. This works perfectly fine.
At the same time however, I try to update the state to the selected element. Because I only want to update the state once the user presses the view/button, I am calling the function inside the event listener. The issue is, that the state is always updated to the last index of the for loop and I am not able to access the index of each element. Can anybody help me with this?

```
const ListRecommendations = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.Data.length; i++) {
  ListRecommendations.push(
    <View key={i}
      style={styles.Recommendation}

      onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {
        Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
          component: {
            name: 'secondScreen',
          }
        });
        this.setState(i);
      }}
      
    >
      <ImageBackground 
        source= {{uri: this.Data[i].FilePath}}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
        <Text style={styles.Title}>{this.Data[i].Title}</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using `TouchableOpacity` and `onPress`?

Comment: The JSX part was generated by a visual builder to get a prototype as soon as possible and I wanted to fix the basic functionality first. As of writing this, I already changed it to TouchableOpacity and onPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use a `var` in you loop but you should know that `var` declaration doesn't work on for block scope, and `i` will be equal the last value

to fix it use `let`

```js
for(let  I=0; I < 10; I++){
  // ...
}
```

Please read more https://javascript.info/variables